# Are C for loops different from PHP for loops?

Tags: php, c, for-loop

It seems like the following from the [PHP manual regarding `for` loops](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) is incorrect.

> They behave like their C counterparts.

This is my understanding of `for` loops.
In C
`for (i = foo; i < 10; i++) {   /* body */ }`
is equivalent to

```
if ( i = foo )  
{   while (i < 10)  
    {    /* body */
         i++;
    }
}
```

In PHP the comparable loop
`for ($i = $foo; $i < 10; $i++) { /* body */ }`
becomes

```
$i = $foo;
while ($i < 10)
{   /* body */
    $i++;
}
```

The difference is that in PHP `$i = $foo` is not a condition but rather a convenient place for a statement.  Suppose we change the single `=` to `==`.  The distinction becomes significant.  Is this correct?  If so, then PHP and C loops behave differently and the manual is incorrect, right?

Comment: I think your understanding of a C for loop is wrong. AFAIK both languages behave like your last code sample.

Comment: It's amazing how long a misconception can stick with me.  I always thought the init expression was a condition and people always put an assignment in there which would evaluate to true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are exactly the same, but your understanding of C's `for` loops is wrong. They are the same as in PHP.

```
 for (x; y; z) { /* body */ }
```

is almost like

```
 x;

 while (y) {
     /* body */
     z;
 }
```

Though the `for` and `while` examples in C are not exactly the same because of scopes and things.

Comment: lol @ "They are exactly the same..." and "It's not exactly the same..."

Comment: @Wiseguy hehe I did not notice that :-P

Comment: @Wiseguy I meant that PHP and C's for loop is exactly the same, but the `for` and `while` examples are not exactly the same.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I know what you meant, but for the sake of clarity, you could instead say something like, "`for` loops work the same in C and PHP... {example}... The only difference between the two is scope..." and elaborate on the scope part a bit. _(Edit: as I see you have now done. Thanks!)_

Answer (score 8):

**This** is **not** true:

```
if ( i = foo )  //what??
{   while (i < 10)  
    {    /* body */
         i++;
    }
}
```

The C for loop is basically:

```
int i = foo; 
while (i < 10)  
 {    /* body */
      i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I learned or spend time with C, but I'm pretty sure the first statement in a C for-loop is an expression setting a variable to a value, just like it is in C.

Answer (score 0):

In C `i=foo` is indeed a condition, it's equivalent to `(i=foo)!=0` since `0` is `false` in C and not-`0` is `true`.

The issue is that C `for` loops don't work the way you think they do, as evidenced by the fact that you can initialize a for loop with `i=0`.